# Can an Arcane Gate spell be facing up or down?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

*Arcane Gate* states:

> *Choose two points on the ground* that you can see, one point within 10 feet of you and one point within 500 feet of you. A circular portal, 10 feet in diameter, opens over each point. [...]
>
> The portals are two-dimensional glowing rings filled with mist, *hovering inches from the ground and perpendicular to it* at the points you choose.

Can the *Arcane Gate* spell in D&D 5e be facing up or down?

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, as your question is really just "what does the ground mean", as evidenced by your answer here.

Answer (score -1):

This depends on the definition of "the ground". 5e uses typical terms in English, unless they are they are specifically [given other meaning as game terms of art](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/179471/what-does-it-mean-for-a-word-or-phrase-to-be-a-game-term). In English, "the ground" is a relative term, since what is clearly ground to a giant might not be ground to a tiny bug. However, this would make the spell work awkwardly for different size classes; we already know it is 10ft in diameter. I would instead say ground is specifically *anything which, as of very recently, counted as a hex or square on which a Medium creature could stand on in the presence of gravity (including with Spider Climb whether active or not)*. The ground would probably include any detritus which would make it be considered Difficult Terrain. For example:

- The rubble staircase of a flying ruined castle would be 'ground' (even though it isn't perfectly flat, it is equivalent to a hill; it has protrusions because it has a bunch of stones; it is wood and not earth and that is fine).
- However furniture and desks (especially if they have function are are searchable) would not count since they are separate items (unless the GM is treating them as Difficult Terrain).
- Vehicles are a bit ambiguous, but any vehicle which is treated as a hex/square you can stand on (e.g. not horses, ambiguously chariots) should probably count, like giving the command word to a *Folding Boat* then (because you are >500ft or somesuch) take an action to summon an Arcane Gate on it should be fine.
- It is ambiguous what happens to the portal if the ground suddenly disappears (if it is destroyed suddenly by the DM in some way in an epic destructive event); obviously the DM may then adjudicate.

Consequently: a portal may be at weird angles, and almost entirely flat or even sticking into the ground, if there exists sufficiently large rubble (e.g. bricks, small boulders, etc.) to change the [normal surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) over a few inches. Or just stick it on a wall (but not a curtain, since it's too flimsy to hypothetically stand on). Otherwise in a flat hallway, the portal would be sticking straight up.